# How to read text file and report based on string

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a VB.net program that reads a text file line by line and reports it.  It works fine, but now i'd like to only read lines that DO NOT end in "F".  For examples My text file may look like this:

```
dlksfjF
kdjflF
EKRJEK
LDKJFLK
oewiur
mkquoi
```

I only want to Display:

```
EKRJEK
LDKJFLK
oewiur
mkquoi
```

My current code is:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)

Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\text.txt")
    Dim line As String = r.ReadLine

    If line <> "*F" Then
        Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
            list.Add(line)
            Console.WriteLine(line)
            line = r.ReadLine
        Loop
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: `File.ReadLines(filename).Where(line => !line.EndsWith("F"))`

Comment: `File.ReadLines(filename).Where(Function(line) (Not line.EndsWith("F")))` (VB.Net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
If line <> "*F" Then
```

Use:

```
If line.EndsWith("F") = False Then
```

It is overloaded so you can also tell it to IgnoreCase and specify cultures as needed.  Example:

```vb
' ignore case and use current culture
If line.EndsWith("F", True, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture ) = False Then

' ignore case and use current culture via string comparison
If line.EndsWith("F", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ) = False Then
```

Outside of VB, the NET namespaces are chockfull of powerful methods and extensions.

Comment: I get "NullReferenceException" was unhandled on the If Line.endswith("F") = False Then

Comment: that is a different problem - you have read past the end of the file. Your loop is inside the IF test for F, so it wont filter them out that way anyway.   Read a Line; test it and add if Ok; repeat.  Note that there is also String.IsNullOrEmpty to test strings, but in this case, the way streamreader is used is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**SOURCE OF THE PROBLEM:**

```
If line <> "*F" Then
```

Is not a pattern comparison with [wildcard character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) - it just compares your `line` with the "*F" string. So any other string like "asdasdF" will come through the condition:

**SOLUTION:**

What you need is probably the [String.EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx) method, and also to put your condition inside the loop:

```
    line = r.ReadLine

    Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
        If (Not line.EndsWith("F")) Then 
             Continue Do
        End If

        list.Add(line)

        Console.WriteLine(line)

        line = r.ReadLine
    Loop
```